# How to prevent more than one "," in a text field

Tags: vba

Does anyone know how I can prevent users from entering more than one comma in a text field using an if statement? For example:

```
if txtWidth.text (contains more than one ",") then
    MsgBox ("Please enter only one comma.")
Else ...
```

What should I put in the place of the first pair of brackets? The program I am making this for is Solidworks.

I have only just started programming and some of the terms are not very clear to me. If it is explained elsewhere and I havent searched properly I apologize.

If someone could help me that would be very nice.
Thank you in advance!

Rob

Comment: If there is no method to directly count char/sequence occurrences in strings, then make one and call it in your if statement. :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `InStr()` function twice :

```
if (InStr(1,txtWidth.Value,",") > 0 ) then
    if (InStr(InStr(1,txtWidth.Value,",") + 1,txtWidth.Value,",") > 0) then
        MsgBox ("Please enter only one comma.")
    end if
end if
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info on `InStr`.

Comment: Thank you al for the quick response, this should get me started nicely I think! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need some nested if statements.

Something like this:

```
If input = "," Then
    If numcommas = 0 Then
        numcommas = 0
    Else
        'Don't allow input of character
    End If
End If
```

You'll need to alter this a little bit in order to use it but this should get you started, or at least give you a geneeral idea of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it with just one if function:

```
If (Len(txtWidth.text) - Len(Replace(txtWidth.text, ",", ""))) > 1 Then
'Your Message'
End If
```

What this code does is it compares the length of your string with the length of your string, cleaned of all commas. So Len("Test,") would give back a length of 5 while Len(Replace("Test,",",","") returns 4 and by substracting those values you get the number of commas in your string.